# Possible to find out if a BigDecimal only has zeros recurring after a certain point?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Specifically, I want to know if it's possible to determine if everything after 2 decimal points will always be a zero.

For example where this is the case:

```
    BigDecimal m1 = new BigDecimal("15");
    BigDecimal m2 = new BigDecimal("2");
    BigDecimal m3 = m1.divide(m2, 5, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
m3 is equal to 7.50000 (and there will still be 0s even if you increase the precision)
```

An example where this is not the case

```
    BigDecimal m1 = new BigDecimal("11.24");
    BigDecimal m2 = new BigDecimal("6");
    BigDecimal m3 = m1.divide(m2, 5, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
m3 is equal to 1.87334
```

Another possible scenario where this will not be the case (can't think of division values) is when

```
 m3 is equal to 7.50000001
```

Thank you for your help (and I apologise if the answer is straightforward/simple!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setScale()` to trim off everything after 2 decimal points, and `compareTo()` to see if it's mathematically equal to the original value:

```
class BigDecimalExperiment {
    static boolean isEverythingAfterTwoDigitsZero(BigDecimal bd) {
        return (bd.compareTo(bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN)) == 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BigDecimal> values = Arrays.asList(
                new BigDecimal("7.5"),
                new BigDecimal("7.50000"),
                new BigDecimal("7.50000001"),
                new BigDecimal("75.01"),
                new BigDecimal(75.01),
                new BigDecimal("75.0100000"),
                new BigDecimal("75.0100001")
        );
        for (BigDecimal value : values) {
            System.out.printf("%s\t%s%n", isEverythingAfterTwoDigitsZero(value), value);
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
true    7.5
true    7.50000
false   7.50000001
true    75.01
false   75.0100000000000051159076974727213382720947265625
true    75.0100000
false   75.0100001
```

Comment: I have to admit [doog's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30629379/27358) is better.

Comment: I like your test cases.  I completely failed to notice the lack of quotes around one of the `75.01` values until I saw its ridiculously long test output.

Answer (score 5):

How about the built-in `stripTrailingZeros`. Then you don't have to do additional rounding calculations.

```
m3.stripTrailingZeros().scale() <= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can round the number both UP and DOWN and compare:

```
BigDecimal m1 = new BigDecimal("15.0001");
System.out.println(m1.round(new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR))
                      .equals(m1.round(new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.CEILING))));
// prints false

m1 = new BigDecimal("15.000");
        System.out.println(m1.round(new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR))
                             .equals(m1.round(new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.CEILING))));
// prints true
```